# Internal error message pops up after each time system is rebooted

Tags: xorg, wubi

I had installed Ubuntu 12.04 using Wubi. But each time I boot the system, an internal error message pops up. As shown below:

```
Executable path
 /usr/share/apport/apport-gpu-error-intel.py

Package
 xserver-xorg-video-intel 2:2.17.0-1ubuntu4

Problem Type
 crash

Apportversion
 2.0.1-0ubuntu7
```

and so on.

I had earlier upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04 from Ubuntu 11.10. And encountered the same issue. Hence I uninstalled the OS and reinstalled using Wubi.

I had posted the same query in ubuntu.com/support (Question Number: 195525) But couldn't find a solution.

I am using Dell Inspiron with Intel Pentium. Need your help in resolving this issue.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Install xdiagnose version 2.5.1, which I uploaded to precise-proposed the other day.

The problem is that the Intel graphics driver has these weird "false gpu hangs".  The GPU locks up but then recovers so that you don't actually notice anything, but it still is enough to trigger the error handler.  Disabling apport doesn't disable this handler; 2.5.1 disables the handler directly.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to disable Apport:

```
sudo gksu gedit /etc/default/apport
```

change "enabled" from "1" to "0", then save the file.

You can always re-enable it later on if you want, by changing "enabled" from "0" back to "1", or you can enable Apport temporarily, using the following command:

```
sudo service apport start force_start=1
```

Comment: Apport is disabled in the release already, so this would have no effect afaik.